# How I print the following sequence of numbers using for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop

The sequence is 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9 12 11.......
Using only for loop in Java
**Any answers are highly appreciated**

And if other point is that we have to print up to n n-1

Comment: Hint: The sequence is the interleaved sequences of all even and odd numbers. Since this seems very much like a homework problem, I hope you can work on the actual implementation yourself (you want to learn, right!).

Comment: How would you print 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ... ?

Comment: For answers to questions of this type you need to look at the sequence, and see if it has any special properties to it. Here, you can see that it swaps odd and even numbers. Hence, you can make a loop that counts by two starting at `1`, and print `i+1` followed by `i` at each step.

Comment: Can you print 1 2 3 4 5 ..... ? Maybe you should try that first. Do you know what is a for loop ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? At which point do you have trouble implementing it on your own? You must know that SO is no *code writing service*, so you probably will get no good answers and down-votes if you just post a *dump of requirements*. Please show some effort and then call back with a specific question.

Comment: To print 2 4 6 8 10 

for (int i = 1 ; i <=10 ; i++){
int a = i*2;
System.out.println(""+a)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 8; //set anything here
    for (int even = 2, odd = 1;even<=n;even+=2,odd+=2){
        System.out.print(even+" "+odd+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code snippet.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 12; i += 2) { System.out.printf("%d %d ", i + 1, i); }`